# Are they going to delete all non USA friendly questions?

Tags: support, status-declined, deleted-questions

Hours ago I posted [a question related to 9/11 and Donald trump](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/20631/why-doesnt-donald-trump-open-a-new-9-11-investigation). This question was polite and direct and it was not just downvoted and closed but deleted.

Is this going to be the trend in this channel. Are all non USA friendly 
questions going to be deleted? Opinions are to be liked or disliked but not to be censored in a free democratic society.

This is an example censorship.

Comment: Even downvoting requests at Meta LOL!

Comment: Downvoting on Meta has a special purpose; it is the way to express one's disagreement, unlike the Main sites. It is recommended for new users to read [faq] to quickly grasp the key concepts.

Answer (score 12):

This site's purpose is to provide a reasonably neutral and expertise-based Q&A platform for questions about Politics. There is very little patience for rants or soapboxing. In other words: it's not reddit, Facebook, YouTube comments, or your uncle's birthday party.

Now, could a "Will Donald Trump open a new investigation in to 9/11?"-question survive on this site? Most certainly! But such a question would not include phrases such as:

> It is well known world wide that the 9/11 attacks were a false flag operation most likely perpetrated by Mossad-CIA

> Anybody with high school physics knowledge can prove it but the media keep calling it "Conspiracy Theory"

> American people are not ready to accept this reality

And so forth.

A good question would state that Donald Trump has hinted at various alternative explanations for 9/11 in the past, and then simply ask a neutral question. No assumptions, no soapboxing, no loaded question. Just an open question.

Even on a less controversial topic, a question with the loaded phrasing you used would be poorly received. Doubly so for conspiracy theories.

And like it or not, the [9/11 Truth Movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9/11_Truth_movement) is widely see as a conspiracy theory, and is rejected as such. If you want to change that then I encourage you to do your best. But ... not here. It's not this site's purpose.

---

Your question on meta also suffers from a extraordinarily poor choice of wording. Not only is not a constructive question but more of a rant, it's also accusing the community of malicious intent, which is a pretty darn rude thing to do.

If you had instead asked "How can I improve this question so it will fit on this site?" I would have upvoted it. Now, I've downvoted it.

Comment: During my affirmations I posted the sources e.g. RT that made such a claim I also made some rhetoric in order to understand the kind of times we are going through.
American people don't want to accept these kind of questions and that's the truth.

Comment: It's not about proving 9/11 was an "inside job" @PbxMan. If you want to ask if Trump will start an investigation about it: *then ask that!*. Your soap boxing of 9/11 is completely unnecessary (and offensive) noise.

Comment: Perhaps instead of deleting other people's opinion you should accept that not everybody has the same views as the American people. Deleting is censorship. Coming from a country that exterminated millions in Vietnam and Iraq for fake reasons get used to delete a lot of comments.

Comment: @PbxMan We are deleting a lot of people's opinions on this website for the simple reason that we don't want to be an opinion platform. We are a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. We want neutral, objective questions about political processes on this website, not opinionated discussions.

Comment: @PbxMan I'll repeat once more, and then I'll stop discussion this: this site is not a platform for soapboxing. Not for the Democratic party. Not for world peace. Not for ending word hunger. Not for stopping racism. Not for animal rights. And ... not for 9/11 conspiracy theories. It's where *experts* can ask and answer questions about *politics*. It's really that simple. As I've stated in my answer, you **can** ask this question, if you would rephrase it to be neutral and remove the soapboxing parts.

Comment: @Philipp are you sure? There are plenty of opinion in other posts. What about my new question? already 2 downvotes and it's going to be closed. Amercians are such a hypocrites (sorry for the opinion)

Comment: Also, FYI, neither Philipp nor myself are American. You personal attacks against "Americans" are also really silly. I also explained *why* this question is getting downvotes and even provided a suggestion on how to improve it.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker silly is deleting and censoring the biggest scam in the 21th century. Fighting to find the truth is what should be done.

Comment: I am finished discussing this @PbxMan. I have tried to genuinely offer advice, and all communication has been a one-way street where all you do is shout and insult and not even appear to listen to what I am saying.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker OK thank you for your tips and my apologies for any offenses. I do think that the world deserves something better than being tossed around by a rouge elite and people should not be treated as cattle.

Comment: Ironically, at least 3 people who closed the original question are not (as far as I'm aware) American :)   I'm tempted to re-ask in a neutral form following @Carpetsmoker's suggested wording but I'm wary of giving Trump more Twitting ideas.